# Why is L'Hôpital's rule giving the wrong answer?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given the following limit:

$$
 \lim_{x \rightarrow -1}  \frac{x^5+1}{x+1} 
$$

The solution using L'Hôpital's rule:

$$
 \lim_{x \rightarrow -1}  \frac{x^5+1}{x+1} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{0}{0} \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow -1}  \frac{5x^4}{1} = 5 \cdot (-1)^4 = -5  
$$

This is wrong. How come?

EDIT: Well, a perfect example of a huge blunder.

Comment: $(-1)^{2k}=1$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 7):

Your application of L'Hôpital's is fine and correct.

The problem is your evaluation/final conclusion...

Recall: $\quad$For $k \in \mathbb N,\;$ $(-1)^n = 1\;$ for (even) $\;n = 2k\,;\;$  $(-1)^n = -1\;$ for (odd) $\;n = 2k+1.\;$

That said, we have: $$5\cdot (-1)^4 = 5\cdot 1 = 5.$$

Comment: Oh, God. I want to cry now.

Comment: Not a problem, we all "goof up", sometimes with "big goofs" - happens to the best of us!

Comment: Effective concise hint :+)

Answer (score 2):

As $\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{x^5+1}{x+1}$ is of the form $\frac00$

It's legal to apply L'Hospital's rule

$$\implies \lim_{x\to-1}\frac{x^5+1}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{5x^4}{1}=5(-1)^4=5$$

---

Alternatively,

as $x^5+1=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$

If $x+1\ne0,$ $\displaystyle\frac{x^5+1}{x+1}=x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$

If $x\to-1,x\ne-1\iff x+1\ne0$

---

Alternatively,

we  can put $x+1=h\implies h\to0$ as $x\to-1$

Comment: He made a "blunder" with evaluating powers. In your (very valid) method there are three powers to evaluate after putting x=-1 :) :)

Comment: @imranfat, have you noticed the edited answer? Without L'Hospital's rule, this is the way, right?

Comment: No, I did not notice the editing, and yes, without Hospital, this is definetely the right way.

Answer (score 1):

It's because $$(-1)^4=1.$$ ${}$